# Crystal Reports table linking with TRIM / OR

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

This is a two part question.

The below needs to be done **WITHOUT** using Command

PART-1

How to link tables that have a '**OR**' in it. Something like:

```
select * from TableA inner join TableB 
on TableA.col1 = TableB.col1 OR TableA.col2 = TableB.col2
```

PART-2

How to link tables that have a **trim** in it. Something like

```
select * from TableA inner join TableB 
on TRIM(TableA.col1) = TRIM(TableB.col1)
```

Please note that both the above needs to be done **without** COMMAND.

how can it be done ?

Thanks !

Comment: I can see you are complicating the issue....explain more about part 1

Comment: well, in my system col1 and col2 refer to two different dates which I need to map. So if 1date fails, the other should be checked.

Comment: What is failing? Didn't get the matched records or getting null....can you explain

Comment: because they are two different dates used in different cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can link both the fields in database expert and you can write your selection in select expert as per your requirement.

For part 2 just link the fields and trim in crystal report formulas